# Rails 4 - create associates records but not parent record in nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4 nested form - I want to create new records for licenses(company has_many licenses) when your company is already existing. How do I achieve it?

**Model - Company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :licenses 
end
```

**Model License.rb**

```
class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

**license_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
  Role.user_role_names.each { |role|  
    @company.licenses.build(license_type: role) 
  }
  @licenses = @company.licenses
end
```

**licenses/views/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @company, url: licenses_path, method: "post" do |f| %>
 <%= f.select :id, Company.get_all_companies, :include_blank => 
  "Select Company", required: true %><br/><br/>

<% @licenses.each do |license|%>
  <%= f.fields_for :licenses, license do |lic| %>
  <div style="border:1px solid; border-radius:10px;width:300px">
    <%= lic.hidden_field :license_type %>

    <%= lic.label :total_licenses, license.license_type.split("_").join(" ").capitalize + " License number"%><br/>
    <%= lic.text_field :total_licenses %><br/><br/>

    <%= lic.label :duration, 'Duration Validity' %><br/>
    <%= lic.text_field :duration %>days<br/><br/>  

  </div>        
<% end %>
<% end %>
<br/><%= f.submit 'Assign'%>&nbsp;
<%= link_to :Back, users_super_admin_index_path %>
<% end %>
```

If you can help me to know how to create licenses record for the existing company that is selected and **company not get created**?

Answer (score 0):

@company = Company.new should be written in companies_controller and not in license_controller.

When the company is selected from the select box set its value in hidden variable, through js, on select of company from dropdown. So when the form is submitted it has @company, so statement: @licenses = @company.licenses will work fine, as it has @company value existing.